# What is equivalent of "its" in german?

Tags: english-to-german

Suppose that there is a paragraph consist of five sentences,but one them is irrelevant and ruins the unity.How could I ask that fact to students?

> Which of the sentences in the given paragraph is irrelevant, violating its unity and coherence?

In this example I dont know which part "its" belongs to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Welcher der Sätze im Absatz ist irrelevant und stört *seine* Gesamtaussage."